# Pre- and post-level activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I am looking for a clean way to implement pre- and post-activities for a central activity, basically pre-level and post-level activities for a game level activity sandwiched in between. The pre- and post-level activities are similar, but have enough differences that I would like to use two different activities with different layouts.

Here's a short rundown of how I imagine the activity ordering (Back would be pressing the back button, action would be interacting with the activity to move forward):

- Main Menu Activity

  - Back -> Quit
  - Action -> Pre-Level Activity
- Pre-Level Activity

  - Back -> Main Menu Activity
  - Action -> Game Activity
- Game Activity

  - Back -> Paused Activity
  - Action -> Post-Level Activity
- Paused Activity

  - Back -> Return to Game Activity
  - Action -> Post-Level Activity
- Post-Level Activity

  - Back -> Main Menu Activity
  - Action -> Pre-Level Activity for next level

Any suggestions for how to best implement such an activity loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this document: [Task and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

If you want to do other operations then activity operations e.g. pause the game. You can handle the onBackPressed() function to do other things then finish the activity